# issue in accessing variable from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, variables

I wrote the following code to store variables in a class for later access from another class:

SettingsController.h

```
@interface SettingsController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isHighway;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isToll;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isVoiceNavigation;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isVoiceCommand;

-(id)initWithHighway:(BOOL)_isHighway;
-(id)initWithToll:(BOOL)_isToll;
-(id)initWithVoiceNavigation:(BOOL)_isVoiceNavigation;
-(id)initWithVoiceCommand:(BOOL)_isVoiceCommand;

-(BOOL)isHighwayOn;
-(BOOL)isTollOn;
-(BOOL)isVoiceNavigationOn;
-(BOOL)isVoiceCommandOn;

@end
```

SettingsController.m

```
@implementation SettingsController

@synthesize isHighway,isToll,isVoiceNavigation,isVoiceCommand;

-(id)initWithHighway:(BOOL)_isHighway{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.isHighway = _isHighway;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithToll:(BOOL)_isToll{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.isToll = _isToll;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithVoiceNavigation:(BOOL)_isVoiceNavigation{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.isVoiceNavigation = _isVoiceNavigation;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithVoiceCommand:(BOOL)_isVoiceCommand{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.isVoiceCommand = _isVoiceCommand;
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isHighwayOn{
    return self.isHighway;
}

-(BOOL)isTollOn{
    return self.isToll;
}

-(BOOL)isVoiceNavigationOn{
    return self.isVoiceNavigation;
}

-(BOOL)isVoiceCommandOn{
    return self.isVoiceCommand;
}

@end
```

From my SettingsViewController Class, I'm initializing values as follows:

```
SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithHighway:isHighways];
```

and access them as

```
BOOL isHighway = [settingsController isHighwayOn];
```

But if I'm trying to access those variable from another class, RouteViewController as follows:

```
SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] init];

BOOL isHighway = [settingsController isHighwayOn];
```

It always give me `0` and I never get `1`.

Could anyone please help me in accessing those variables?

## EDIT

OK, I've removed the `SettingsController` and taking its interface to the `RouteViewController`. I'm initializing from `SettingsViewController` as follows:

```
RouteViewController *routeController = [[RouteViewController alloc] initWithHighway:isHighways];
```

then accessing it from RouteViewController by simply:

```
NSLog(@"Highway: %d",self.isHighway);
```

Even then it always giving me `0` never `1`.

## EDIT

For just maintaining these 4 UISwich in my SettingsViewController I'm now using NSUserDefaults. I think it's a better way to do so... Thanks for all of your help...

Comment: Where do you set the BOOLs' value? They all start out 0, so if you don't set their value, naturally, you will receive 0 and not 1.

Comment: I'm using an UISwitch to toggle the BOOL values

Comment: Your edit is not clear. Please, explain better the changes you applied to your code, otherwise it's difficult to understand where you put your code and why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want this class to store 4 variables, but you've got 4 initializers, which is kind of an unusual way to do it.  I don't know the rest of your application but is it common to want to create this class to store just one variable?

Anyway, as ThomasM said, if you set the value to YES it should come back out as YES.

```
BOOL isHighways = YES;
SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithHighway:isHighways];
NSLog(@"Highways?  %@", settingsController.isHighwayOn ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

This should print YES.

Note that you're creating properties but you're also creating an accessor method.  That's redundant - settingsController.isHighway and settingsController.isHighwayOn would return the same value.

(And read the other answer about making it a singleton - unless you persist these properties somewhere, every instance of the class will have its own set of values).

Comment: It is printing YES in this way. OK, I've removed the SettingsController and taking its interface to the RouteViewController. I'm initializing from SettingsViewController as follows:

RouteViewController *routeController = [[RouteViewController alloc] initWithHighway:isHighways];

then accessing it from RouteViewController by simply:

NSLog(@"Highway: %d",self.isHighway);

Even then it always giving me 0 never 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use singleton object for SettingsController, or pass the initialized one somehow. Note that at first you create object:`SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithHighway:isHighways];` and then instead of reusing it, you initialize new one in: `SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] init];`. So it does not contain previosly initiated variables.

Answer (score 0):

As ThomasM pointed out in the comments, you didn't initialize your `isHighway` variable. Since you didn't re-implement `init` method for `SettingsController` class, when you call

```
SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] init];
```

you call the default initializer, which does not init your `isHighway` variable (or, better, `isHighway` is initialized to 0).

Try to re-implement your `init` method, as example:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        isHighWay = 1;
    }

    return self;
 }
```

Comment: Let me explain it for better understanding:

I've a SettingsViewController and it contains 4 UISwitch. I'm using them to store [UISwitch isOn] value in SettingsController class. Then I'm trying to access those BOOL values in RouteViewController class. When I'm accessing the SettingsController's BOOL values in RouteViewController I'm always getting 0 though the value was stored as 1 from SettingsViewController.

Comment: You're right. By the way, for just maintaining these 4 UISwich in my SettingsViewController I'm now using NSUserDefaults. I think it's a better way to do so... Thanks for all of your help...